# Error to connect to Thingsboard local server

Tags: python, thingsboard

I'm trying to send data to Thingsboard, which server is located in another computer at the same network.

I can open it in my computer, using the address `xxx.xxx.x.xx1:pppp`.

Device is created, his access token is `device_access_token`.

My code, which runs in python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import nidaqmx
from datetime import datetime
import time
from tb_device_mqtt import TBDeviceMqttClient, TBPublishInfo

t_0=time.time_ns()

client = TBDeviceMqttClient("xxx.xxx.x.xx1", ppp, "device_access_token")

now = datetime.now()
dt_name = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
filename = dt_name + ".txt"

def envia(valor_0, valor_1):
    telemetry = {"T0": float(valor_0) }
    if not client.is_connected() :
        client.connect() #line 19
    client.send_telemetry(telemetry)
    result = client.send_telemetry(telemetry)
    success = result.get() == TBPublishInfo.TB_ERR_SUCCESS

    telemetry = {"T1": float(valor_1) }
    if not client.is_connected() :
        client.connect() #line 26
    client.send_telemetry(telemetry)
    result = client.send_telemetry(telemetry)
    success = result.get() == TBPublishInfo.TB_ERR_SUCCESS #linha 29

p, t = [1,2] 
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    print("running")
    task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("6008/ai0:1")
    task.timing.cfg_samp_clk_timing(1000)
    t_0=time.perf_counter_ns()
    while (1):
        f   = open(filename, "a")
        for i in range (1000):
            p, t = task.read()
            t_a = time.perf_counter_ns()-t_0
            p = 2000*p/-9.418  
            t = 20*t
            f.write(str(t_a)+','+str(t)+','+str(p)+'\n')
            envia(p, t) #line 45
        f.close()
        print("dados salvos")
```

The error message that I receive:

```
C:\Users\ange_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py:1779: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=1796, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('xxx.xxx.x.xx2', 49172), raddr=('xxx.xxx.x.xx1', pppp)
   `self.reconnect()`
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
C:\Users\ange_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py:1083: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=2264, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('xxx.xxx.x.xx2', 49276), raddr=('xxx.xxx.x.xx1', pppp)>
  `self.\_sock = sock`
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Documents\Facul\Rota 2030\Codigos\Codigos_2023\Thingsboard_NI\teste.py", line 45, in <module>
    envia(p, t) #line 45
  File "e:\Documents\Facul\Rota 2030\Codigos\Codigos_2023\Thingsboard_NI\teste.py", line 29, in envia
    success = result.get() == TBPublishInfo.TB_ERR_SUCCESS #linha 29
  File "C:\Users\ange_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tb_device_mqtt.py", line 143, in get
    self.message_info.wait_for_publish(timeout=1)
  File "C:\Users\ange_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 362, in wait_for_publish
    raise RuntimeError ('Message publish failed: %s' % (error_string(self.rc)))
RuntimeError: `Message publish failed: The client is not currently connected.`
```

I'm following [this example - line 30](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard-python-client-sdk/blob/d4f65276df04ef4a9358ac3c2320ad2baaa5ff8b/examples/device/send_telemetry_and_attr.py).

In most examples, the IP is always the same: 127.0.0.1. I tried it too, but I think I use it just when I'm working directly on the server.

Comment: The link to the "this example - line 29" is wrong. Please, correct it.

Comment: @JuanmiTaboada thanks for the advice, and sorry for my delay to correct it, I wasn't at work these days.